# How to keep an actor inside the stage in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm creating a game using libgdx and I'm using stage and actors for the entities inside the game. but the problem is I cant keep the actor inside the stage or the screen. when i drag the actor in the lowest, highest, left most, or right most of my screen it goes out of the screen. I want it to stay inside the screen.

What should I do? please help.

this is the strip of code i use for dragging my actor

> ```
> addListener(new DragListener(){
>
>        @Override
>        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
>            camera.unproject(dimension.set(x, y, 0));
>            System.out.println("clicked "+ x +","+y);
>            return true;
>        }
>
>        @Override
>        public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
>            moveBy(x-(getWidth()/2),y-(getHeight()/3));
>        }
>
>        @Override
>        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
>            super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
>        }
>    });
> ```

Comment: You can't keep it "inside" `Stage`, as a `Stage` has no size as much as i remember. Also keeping it inside the `Screen` is somehow problematic, think about a moving `Camera`. So what you should do intead is define a world size and limit the `Actor`s position to this size. Then you should create a `Camera` or even better a `Viewport` (thats another theme covered by many tutorials) with the size of your world. Now center the `Camera` so that you can see exactly your world on the `Screen`.

Comment: Think in terms of keeping it within the camera's bounds. Clamp your move-to position to keep the target location within camera position +/- camera.viewportWidth and Height.

Comment: so i have a Camera and a Viewport but how do i set the world size? please help.. how can i limit it?

Answer (score 1):

`Stage` does have `getWidth` and `getHeight` methods. They return world sizes managed by the internal `Viewport`. `Window` class has optional dragging behavior and `keepWithinStage` parameter.

This is a code snippet from LibGDX 1.8.0 (`Window` class):

```
        public void touchDragged (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            if (!dragging) return;
            float width = getWidth(), height = getHeight();
            float windowX = getX(), windowY = getY();

            float minWidth = getMinWidth(), maxWidth = getMaxWidth();
            float minHeight = getMinHeight(), maxHeight = getMaxHeight();
            Stage stage = getStage();
            boolean clampPosition = keepWithinStage && getParent() == stage.getRoot();

            if ((edge & MOVE) != 0) {
                float amountX = x - startX, amountY = y - startY;
                windowX += amountX;
                windowY += amountY;
            }
            if ((edge & Align.left) != 0) {
                float amountX = x - startX;
                if (width - amountX < minWidth) amountX = -(minWidth - width);
                if (clampPosition && windowX + amountX < 0) amountX = -windowX;
                width -= amountX;
                windowX += amountX;
            }
            if ((edge & Align.bottom) != 0) {
                float amountY = y - startY;
                if (height - amountY < minHeight) amountY = -(minHeight - height);
                if (clampPosition && windowY + amountY < 0) amountY = -windowY;
                height -= amountY;
                windowY += amountY;
            }
            if ((edge & Align.right) != 0) {
                float amountX = x - lastX;
                if (width + amountX < minWidth) amountX = minWidth - width;
                if (clampPosition && windowX + width + amountX > stage.getWidth()) amountX = stage.getWidth() - windowX - width;
                width += amountX;
            }
            if ((edge & Align.top) != 0) {
                float amountY = y - lastY;
                if (height + amountY < minHeight) amountY = minHeight - height;
                if (clampPosition && windowY + height + amountY > stage.getHeight())
                    amountY = stage.getHeight() - windowY - height;
                height += amountY;
            }
            lastX = x;
            lastY = y;
            setBounds(Math.round(windowX), Math.round(windowY), Math.round(width), Math.round(height));
        }
```

You can simplify this by clamping the X to 0 and `stage.getWidth() - actor.getWidth()` and doing the same for Y.